# Confused about the Fourier Transform of $e^{at}u(t)$

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, continuous-signals

This is the problem at hand:
[image: Snapshot from Oppenheimer's]

I'm unaware of why we didn't have to say anything about $\omega$ like that it should be also greater than $0$, I know it's variable...but it's multiplied by $t$ whatsoever.

Also, if $a$ is complex, I don't understand why do we require that $Re \{a\} >0$ only, without mentioning anything about the imaginary part (it's mentioned further down in the book).

Finally, why isn't it $Re\{a\}>=0$? is it because that may reduce to the Heaviside step function if the imaginary part of $a$ is also 0?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. $\omega$'s value does nothing for the convergence of the integral. $a$'s does.
2. $a$ is not complex, it's real only.
3. If $a$ is 0, the integral doesn't converge.

Comment: 1- Even though I believe it's true, I'm not entirely sure why is that the case.

2- I wouldn't have asked about this if it wasn't mentioned in Oppenheimer's book that "Note that if a is complex rather than real, then $x(t)$ is absolutely integrable as long
as $Re\{a\} > 0$"

3- Isn't it the case that if $a$ is 0, then it reduces to finding the Fourier series of the unit step function?

Thank you.

Comment: 1- $|e^{-j\omega t}| = 1\ \  \forall \omega, t$. 2- OK. 3- [Yes, but read this.](https://www.cs.uaf.edu/~bueler/M611heaviside.pdf)

Comment: it's sorta funny how representing the unit step as $$ u(t) \triangleq \tfrac12 + \tfrac12\operatorname{sgn}(t) $$ results in Fourier Transform $$ \mathscr{F}\{u(t)\} = U(f) = \tfrac12 \delta(f) + \frac{1}{j 2 \pi f} $$ and i s'pose the $f$ in $\delta(f)$ is a little bit nonzero even if imaginary it's not there.  if we do analytic continuation $s = \sigma + j 2 \pi f$ and back substitute, if $\sigma \ne 0$ then the $\delta\left(-j\frac{s-\sigma}{2\pi} \right)=0$ and you get  $$ \mathscr{L}\{u(t)\} = \frac{1}{s} $$ Why isn't it $$ \mathscr{L}\{u(t)\} = \frac{1}{s-\sigma} $$ ?